# How to include a "custom" library in Code::Blocks? (Windows 7)

Tags: c++, dll, include, shared-libraries, codeblocks

Ok, I've never did this before and I'm having problems to understand how it works (Especially the "include" part). Here's my code:

```
#include <joypp1.02/app.h>
#include <joypp1.02/objects.h>

void event_plot()
{
    if (App::event_type() == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
    {
        App::shut_down();
    }
    if (App::event_type() == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        if (App::event().keyboard.keycode == ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE)
        {
            App::shut_down();
        }
        if (App::event().keyboard.keycode == ALLEGRO_KEY_ENTER)
        {
            cout << "Whatever! ";
        }
    }
}

void visual_plot()
{
    static Image x("sample.png");
    x.draw();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    App app(800, 600);
    app.set_background_color(200, 0, 0);
    app.add_event_scene(Scene("Event Plot", event_plot));
    app.add_visual_scene(Scene("Visual Plot", visual_plot));
    app.run();
    return 0;
}
```

joypp1.02 is the dynamic-link library I've compiled, and it's in its own "output" folder (Together with the import file):

[image]

joypp1.02 has only two headers: app.h e objects.h. How do I import them? The library is in the linker (I want to keep it in the output folder of the library, because It's in constant development. BUT, I want to compile it **only** as a DLL, so I have a separate project that **uses** the DLL).

[image]

And the folder with the joypp1.02.dll is in the Search Directories of the compiler.

[image]

And if I try to include like this:

```
#include "joypp1.02.h"
```

I get:

```
fatal error: joypp1.02.h: No such file or directory
```

So, I'm lost. How to include a "custom" library in Code::Blocks in Windows? How do I know the include name? Why it's a header like "joypp1.02.h" if it's a .a file?

Disclaimer: I've used the word "custom" to emphasize that it was written and compiled by me (So, probably more problems than just importing some "official" and "pro" one).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've solved it. I was missing the point of the actual function of a dynamic-link library. I was forgetting to include the header files (And I've remembered from other libraries that, indeed, I include their .h files apart from the .a or .lib import library files, and the binary .dll(s) (I thought they were **inside** the import library file or something, and that only the import library and .dll were required)).

So you, possible reader from the future, in face of the same problem: Hear me! **You must make the header files of your library visible to the compiler** (Include in the "search directories", in the compiler tab in Code::Blocks), and at the same time, **link the import library .a or .lib file**, AND, if no search directory is specified under the linker tab, **have the .dll binary in the folder of your application**.

If by any means, you're still lost, read this:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_(errors)#Q:_What_do_I_need_to_know_when_using_3rd_party_libs.3F